# Setting up WAMP dev environment using subversion

Tags: svn, wamp

I have been working on a site for a while using Dreamweaver and uploading the changes via the built-in FTP. I realize now that this is a dumb setup. I have no way to test files in a non-production environment, and I have no source control. I suck.

I want to improve this setup, but I'm a bit lost. Is my understanding correct?

1. Setup development environment on my local machine (I would use WAMP).
2. Setup subversion server on the production server with a repository based on the /www directory
3. Develop and test locally
4. When ready to move to production, commit to subversion on the production server.

Am I on the right track? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track. You might want to use Vagrant too so you have the same environment with your production server. Then use git.

Comment: I am running into lots of problems with my included files because of path differences between production and my local machine.  Is there a best practice for handling that, or is that why you suggest Vagrant to duplicate the environments?